# Symfony2 & Doctrine2 : removeElement doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm have a small project in Symfony2 and doctrine, and I'm trying to update 2 related entities:

**Members & cars**

```
$carMembers = $car->getMembers();
echo count($carMembers); // --> show 2
echo get_class(carMembers[0]); // --> show MyCars\WSBundle\Entity\Member
$car->removeMember($member);
$em->persist($car);
$em->flush();

$carMembers= $car->getMembers();
echo count($carMembers); // --> show 1
echo get_class(carMembers[0]); // --> show MyCars\WSBundle\CarsController !!!
```

there is my Entities:

**Car**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Member", mappedBy="cars")
 */
private $members;

/**
 * Remove Member
 *
 * @param MyCars\WSBundle\Entity\Member $member
 */
public function removeMember(\MyCars\WSBundle\Entity\Member $member)
{
    $this->members->removeElement($member);
    $member->removeCar($this);
}
```

**Member**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Car", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="cars_membres",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="member_id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="car_id", referencedColumnName="car_id")}
 * )
 */
private $cars;
```

Comment: if you want to remove an object (= a line in your database) you can simply use `$em->remove($yourobject); $em->flush();` no need to create a removeMember function

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I want to keep it in database, I just want to remove the relation between Members and cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to initialise the ArrayCollection in the class constructor, if you want to use the functions **add**, **contains** or **removeElement**

```
<?php

// ...

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Car
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $members;

    /**
     * General constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param Member $member
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addMember(Member $member)
    {
        if (!$this->hasMember($member)) {
            $this->members->add($member);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Member $member
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeMember(Member $member)
    {
        if ($this->hasMember($member)) {
            $this->members->removeElement($member);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * @param Member $member
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function hasTag(Member $member)
    {
        return $this->members->contains($member);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I think what you're looking for is `orphanRemoval` relation option.

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Car", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
```

So when you remove item from collection and flush entity manager it will remove relation record from database...

Comment: When I add orphanRemoval, I get this Error : `Unknown property orphanRemoval; on annotation : Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany`
It's work only with OneToMany or one-to-many associations.

Answer (score 0):

Which Collection do you use? Do you use \Doctrine\ArrayCollecion?
Are you sure that you are removing the same member object instance?
removeElement() method removes an object from the collection only if it is the same instance.

here is the method (note the last parameter (true) in the array_search method:

```
public function removeElement($element)
{
  $key = array_search($element, $this->_elements, true);

  if ($key !== false) {
    unset($this->_elements[$key]);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```