# Symfony2 form collection allow_delete not working

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I have made a "collection" form like described in documentation (http://symfony.com/fr/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), and  like i did before on other projects.

It seems that allow_delete doesn't work : when i delete embedded forms, the data in the request is ok but after calling submit function on the form, they still on the object like it  was before. It seems like it merges old data with request data, and i don't see why ...

Adding embedded forms works great, only deleting is not working.

Comment: add your code to the question please ? Otherwise we can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Even though you don't give a lot information, I think this question is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197483/delete-an-item-from-onetomany-relationship or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465474/symfony2-doctine2-removeelement-doesnt-work. If not, please add some code to your question.

Comment: Finally it was an issue from the symfony version ...

Comment: what version you used?